# Какие есть цвета usb-разъёмов и что они означают?

Tags: usb, железо, разъёмы

Для usb распространено окрашивание разъёмов в различные цвета с целью сделать их легкоразличимыми визуально. Например, разъёмы usb 3 обычно делают синими, а разъёмы, пригодные только для зарядки, красными или жёлтыми. Есть ли собственные цвета у usb 3.1, 3.2 и 4? В случае кабеля, влияет ли как-то максимально допустимый ток? Для чего используется сиреневый цвет?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> В спецификации сказано строго "рекомендуем использовать только **синий**".

Но подробнее о цветах:

- Белый это USB 1.x
- Серый это USB 2.x
- Синий это USB 3
- Красный или желтый это USB 3 - это говорит о том, что разъём не будет выключен во время сна или в режиме ожидания. Тут отмечу, что в спецификации на этот счёт ничего не сказано (может специалисты меня поправят). Часто красный используются для повышенного питания, но на практике я не встречал.

По факту порт должен быть всегда синий. Других цветов в спецификации я не встречал.

USB 3.1, 3.2 тоже синий, красный или жёлтый.

---

USB 4 - точной спецификации нет

Из спецификации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PDF спецификации, страница 5-14. [Ссылка](https://www.usb3.com/whitepapers/USB%203%200%20(11132008)-final.pdf).

Comment: А что с сиреневым? https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQiAz.png Встречал на двух кабелях usb - usb-c, оба на 5 ампер, один заявлен как usb 3.1, на втором не уточняется.

Comment: Кстати, к меня синие usb3 на компе не выключаются при выключении питания, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @Qwertiy скорее всего прихоти производителя. Я встречал зеленый usb у флешки корейского производство.

Comment: @Qwertiy всё верно синий. В спецификации сказано строго "ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ СИНИЙ". А какие у него  будут функции это уже другой разговор.

Comment: @Qwertiy немного дополнил ответ.

Comment: А если смотреть спецификацию usb-c, а не usb3?

Comment: @Qwertiy usb-c вообще не регламентирует цвет... там же и сам тип разъема уже другой. Собственно там даже нечего в другой цвет красить)

Comment: [Пошли в твой чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90963/discussion-between-by-verng-and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 7):

Насколько я знаю, обычно:

- **Чёрный** - USB 1 (позже USB 2);
- **Белый** - USB 2;
- **Синий** - USB 3;
- **Красный** - интерфейс повышенного напряжения, передаваемые ток свыше 500 мА;
- **Жёлтый** -  интерфейс, который передает ток даже при выключенном компьютере (предполагает использование для зарядки различного оборудования, независимо от состоянии компьютера).

Здесь ключевое слово "обычно", т.к. на самом деле многое зависит от производителя и модели мат.платы. Видел модели, где все порты красного цвета, но не потому, что они для зарядки. Просто так захотелось дизайнеру.

Comment: Usb3 - это 1 ампер, насколько я помню. А красный получается ток больше чем в usb2? И что с сиреневым? https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQiAz.png Встречал на двух кабелях usb - usb-c, оба на 5 ампер, один заявлен как usb 3.1, на втором не уточняется.